# regex detecting single line

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

Need regex for detecting string in only single line,i tried this regex `\"(\\.|[^"\\])*\"` but this works also with multiline
input:

**Example :**

```
this is a "string
and the string ends here"
```

i want the regex to detect only the string in the first line  ("string)

what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression recognises multiple lines because

```
[^"\\]
```

accepts a newline character: it accepts anything other than a quote (`"`) or a backslash (`\`), and a newline is neither a quote nor a backslash. Add newline (`\n`) to the list of excluded characters.

Note that in (f)lex, `.` actually means `[^\n]`: anything other than a newline. It does not mean "match anything". So `\\.` matches a backslash followed by anything other than a newline. But many languages allow you to use a backslash to escape newlines as well:

```
"This long string is \
continued on a second line."
```

That's not a requirement, of course, and string literal concatenation is probably a more useful syntax. It all depends on your precise requirements.

Answer (score -1):

(.*)\n

this much is enough I think?

\A(.*)\n

this can help if there are more than two lines